# How to connect words from two lists in Java

Tags: java, string, list, java-stream, stringbuilder

I want to create a sentence from words from two different lists. Like the example above:

> "list1w1 list2w1 list1w2 list2w2 list1w3 list2w3..."

I know how to do it with for loop, but I want to use streams. Is it even possible?

My current solution:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<doses.size(); i++)
result.append(String.format("%s %s<br>", list1.get(i), list2.get(i)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IntStream`:

```
String res = IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%s %s", list1.get(i), list2.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("<br>"));
```

Comment: `String.format` might be overkill here, compared to a plain `.mapToObj(i -> list1.get(i) + " " + list2.get(i))`

Answer (score 2):

You may do it like so,

```
IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%s %s", list1.get(i), list2.get(i)))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("<br>"));
```

And here's another way of doing it.

```
IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.mapping(i -> list1.get(i) + " " + list2.get(i), 
        Collectors.joining("<br>")));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to solve this problem.

Using Streams with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) `Collectors2.zip()`:

```
List<String> one = Arrays.asList("list1w1", "list1w2", "list1w3");
List<String> two = Arrays.asList("list2w1", "list2w2", "list2w3");

String output = one.stream().collect(Collectors2.zip(two))
        .collect(pair -> pair.getOne() + ' ' + pair.getTwo())
        .makeString("<br>");
```

Using Eclipse Collections APIs directly:

```
String output = LazyIterate.zip(one, two)
        .collect(pair -> pair.getOne() + ' ' + pair.getTwo())
        .makeString("<br>");
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is a flatMap.

Something along the lines of:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

List<String> result = list1.stream()
        .flatMap(s1 -> list2.stream().map(s2 -> s1 + s2))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

This will print `[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]` which is what you're looking for

Comment: No, if you use `flatmap`, that implies the "traditional" way is to use nested `for` loops. The OP has only one `for` loop. The required output is just `[a1, b2, c3]`. The other two answers have given the correct answer (they are, in fact, identical).

Comment: His example really contradicts his code though, I went for the example output :)

Comment: Check the example again carefully. It doesn't contradict his code. List1 = a b c. List 2 = 1 2 3. His example: "list1w1 list2w1 list1w2 list2w2 list1w3 list2w3" = "a1 b2 c3". Note that list1w1 = a, list2w1 = 1.